# How to remove the side panel that pop up when you click on a layer?

Tags: contextmenu, menuitem, layer, side-menu

I have made a google map and added a single layer. However, when I preview the map and click on the layer a side panel comes up with the layer title on the left. This is blocking the map. Is there a way to stop this side panel coming up when you click on the layer? I would greatly apprechiate any help. I have googled everywhere and come up with no solution. Thank you, Emily

I have tried to turn off labels but it didn't stop the side panel coming up when you click on the layer.